# Merge Sort doesn't work for a table of integers with more than 521096 elements

Tags: c, sorting, mergesort

I am trying to sort a large table of integers using different types of sorting algorithms like quick sort, bubble sort and merge Sort, all of these algorithms works just fine. However, When trying to sort a table with more than than 521096 elements using Merge Sort, the program just exits without throwing any error(I'm guessing in C this is a runtime error)

Note that Merge Sort works perfectly with a table that contains less than 921096 elements.
Note also that for example Quick Sort works fine with tables of any length(I've tried up to 1 Million elements).

Here is the code I'm using:

```
void fillTable(int *t,int n){
    srand(time(NULL));
    int signe=1;
    for(int *p=t;p<t+n;p++){
        *(p)=signe*rand()%n;
        signe*=-1;
    }
}
void mergeTables(int *tab,int l,int m,int r){
    int i,j,k;
    int n1=m-l+1;
    int n2=r-m; 


    int lTab[n1],rTab[n2];

    for(i=0;i<n1;i++){
        lTab[i]=tab[l+i];
    }
    for(i=0;i<n2;i++){
        rTab[i]=tab[m+1+i];
    }

    i=0;j=0;k=l;
    while(i<n1 && j<n2){
        if(lTab[i]<=rTab[j]){
            tab[k]=lTab[i];
            i++;
        }
        else{
            tab[k]=rTab[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    while(i<n1){
        tab[k]=lTab[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    while(j<n2){
        tab[k]=rTab[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
}

void diviserTab(int *tab,int l,int r){
    if(r>l){
        int m=(r+l)/2;
        diviserTab(tab,l,m);
        diviserTab(tab,m+1,r);
        mergeTables(tab,l,m,r);
    }
}
void mergeSort(int* t,int n){
        diviserTab(t,0,n-1);
}
double getTime(void(*f)(int*,int),int* t,int n){
    clock_t start,end;
    start=clock();
    f(t,n);
    end=clock();
    return (double)(end-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}
```

and here is my Main:

```
int main(){

int *tab;
int i;
int n=521096;
tab=(int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
fillTable(tab,n);
printf("First 10 elements before sorting");
for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    printf("%5d\t",tab[i]);
}

printf("%f\n",getTime(mergeSort,tab,n));
printf("\nFirst 10 elements before sorting\n");
for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    printf("%5d\t",tab[i]);
}


return 0;
```

}

Now to the results:
 if n=521095 (number of elements in the array)

```
First 10 elements before sorting
18187   -12205  23363   -27523  30572   -31906   5475   -10341   5178   -27678
it took 0.179000 to sort the array

First 10 elements after sorting
-32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32767  -32766  -32766  -32766
```

if n=521096

```
First 10 elements before sorting
18243   -31088  32141   -10616   9312    -356   25619   -26113  23731   -21465
```

(and it just exits)

Comment: You've come to the right place ;) - my suggestion would be to allocate the temp tables from the heap - and don't forget to free them again when done with them.

Comment: Thank you sir, I can't believe I didn't think of that .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are allocating some large arrays on the stack. From your `mergeTables` function:

```
int lTab[n1],rTab[n2];
```

With a large array to sort, `n1` and `n2`, and therefore `lTab` and `rTab`, can become large (half the size of your initial array), and the stack is typically fairly small. If the arrays don't fit, all sorts of strange things can happen. When I tried your program with a large array (10 million integers), the program crashed.

Quicksort and bubble sort are usually performed in situ, so I assume you didn't need all this extra space for them.

I changed your two arrays to this:

```
int *lTab = malloc(n1 * sizeof(int));
int *rTab = malloc(n2 * sizeof(int));
```

And then at the end of the function:

```
free(lTab);
free(rTab);
```

Comment: Thank you Thomas Padron McCarthy, this worked perfectly.